# Cabal install refuses to install module because of missing cabal library

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

I am really desperate with this one. Trying to install `mtl` for my `ghc`, so I installed `cabal-install` package (I am running Fedora 23). Then I tried to run `cabal update` which finished OK, but `cabal install mtl` gives me this.

```
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring transformers-0.5.2.0...
Failed to install transformers-0.5.2.0
Last 10 lines of the build log ( /home/metthal/.cabal/logs/transformers-0.5.2.0.log ):
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
mtl-2.2.1 depends on transformers-0.5.2.0 which failed to install.
transformers-0.5.2.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
user error (The package 'transformers' requires Cabal library version -any &&
>=1.6 but no suitable version is installed.)
```

The mentioned log file is completely empty. The package `ghc-Cabal` is installed. `cabal --version` reports this.

```
cabal-install version 1.18.1.0
using version 1.18.1.5 of the Cabal library
```

I also tried `cabal install cabal-install` but that gave me just the same errors on all the dependencies.

I really don't understand it anymore and I am out of ideas how to solve this issue. Googling doesn't help as it seems I am the only one with this kind of problem. I appreciate any help.

Comment: What GHC is this, anyway?

Comment: `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4`

Comment: If you are really desperate, you can use stack: http://haskellstack.org/ . It's better tool in my opinion.

Comment: why desperate - IMO it's the recommended way by now ;)

Comment: Clearly there is a mismatch between the cabal version you think it is using, and the actual version which it is using. You should ensure that 1. you have a single copy of the `cabal` executable on your filesystem, and 2. you have at most one copy of every package in your global and user package databases. It looks like you're installing in the global package database - if there is some inconsistency this will often lead to cryptic errors like this one. You should try installing in a sandbox, or use stack (which handles all this "automagically" for you). Also run with -v3 if you want to debug..

Comment: What does `ghc-pkg list Cabal` say?

Comment: Thanks everyone for help. I have managed to resolve it with completely removing everything related to `ghc` and `cabal` then installing it again. It seems to work. However, `stack` seems like an interesting tool so I will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

For the record (although this is apparently resolved), the issue is that `cabal` is the cabal install tool, but `Cabal` in the error message refers to a library, so running a `ghc-pkg list` to check if that library is installed and what version would have been the appropriate next step.